# Receiving result from .ajax function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: {
        content, content
   }
});
```

I was wondering how I could get a callback from tosql.php (the result) and add that html to `div class = "content"`

Comment: Also  read jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do that within the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: {
        content: content
    },
    success: function(html) {

        // you said 'add' so I'm assuming '.append'
        // if you meant fill/replace then use `.html(html);`
        $("div.content").append(html);
    }
});
```

Also (if it's not a typo on your part), object property names and values are separated by the colon:

```
    data: {
        content: content
    },
```

and not the comma:

```
    data: {
        content, content
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe this code is true and solve your problem..
**data : mydata**
**success: resultdt**

```
var mydata = $(".form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: mydata,
    sucess: resultdt
});


function resultdt(data,status){
   data=$.trim(data);
   $(".c").html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: {
        content: content
   },
   success:function(data)
   {
      jQuery('#target').html(data);
    }
});
```